# Injectivity - Problem Confusion

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For any $x \in A$, let $E_x \in \left \{ y \in A : yRx \right \}$ be the equivalence class of $x$ w.r.t. $R$. Let $E = \left \{ E_x : x \in A \right \}$ be the
collection of all equivalence classes.

Prove that the function $h: E \to B$ defined by $h(E_x) = f(x)$ is injective.

I am a bit confused by this question. I know the definition of injectivity and have shown it before for other questions. First, what is $B$? My comfort with eequivalence classes is pretty slim as well. An equivalence class is the set of elements that are *equivalent* to each other. (right?).

$E_x \in \left \{ y \in A : yRx \right \}$ ? So this is saying that for the relation $yRx$ to exist, $y$ must be in $A$? But why does this make this an Equivalent Relation of $x$?

Comment: Well, it looks like $R$ is an equivalence relation determined by a function $f$. However, since you (or you problem sheet lol) haven't provided that information it will be pretty hard for me or others to help.

Comment: I am guessing that f is a function from A to B, and that the equivalence relation is defined on A by yRx iff f(x)=f(y).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's suppose that the problem actually says that there is a function $f : A \to B$, where $A$ and $B$ are some sets, and that $R$ is indeed defined by $x R y$ iff $f(x) = f(y)$.

To show $h$ is injective, we usually start by saying

"Suppose $h(E_x) = h(E_y)$; we will show that $E_x = E_y$."

Let's look at what that conclusion means. If $E_x = E_y$, it means "the set of things equivalent to $x$ is the same as the set of things equivalent to $y$." That means that $xRy$. In other words, we could instead have written this:

"Suppose $h(E_x) = h(E_y)$; we will show that $x R y$."

So...what does it mean for $h(E_x) = h(E_y)$? Well, look at the definition, follow your nose, and see what comes out.

Does this help, or should I write out the rest of the proof?

(By the way, the definition of $h$ is remarkably sloppy -- to some degree, that definition needs justification as well!)

Comment: So, for $h(E_x) = h(E_y)$, it means that $f(x) = f(y)$ right? Since $h(E_x) = f(x)$ then $h(E_y) = f(y)$. Then we show that $f(x) = f(y)$ is injective (which it is). Is this right?

Comment: Right. You say "Suppose $h(E_x) = h(E_y)$. Then, by the definition of $h$, we have $f(x) = f(y)$. And then by the definition of $R$, we have $x R y$. But $x R y$ means that $E_x = E_y$. We have shown that whenever $h(E_x) = h(E_y)$, we have $E_x = E_y$. That means $h$ is injective."

Comment: Ah, okay. Thanks for the help~